# How to Pass one additional parameter in spring security login form

Tags: mysql, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working one project in which spring security implemented for login auth. Now we want to that when user login it connect to which database depends one parameter which is i pass during login and want to access this parameter on home.jsp page my code as:

1)login page url

/login

```
     <form action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" id="login"   method="POST">              
        <input type="text" id="userid" name='j_username' placeholder="Your User Name"/>

        <input id="password" type="password" name='j_password'  placeholder="Password" />

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
    </form>
```

2) spring form login as

```
<form-login always-use-default-target="true"  login-page="/login" default-target-url="/home"  authentication-failure-url="/login"  />
```

3) AccessDecissionManager class

```
public class CustomAccessDecisionManager extends AbstractAccessDecisionManager {

    public void decide(Authentication authentication, Object filter,Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes){

        // get all roles from ldap    
        checkAllowIfAllAbstainDecisions();
    }

}
```

4. url for home.jsp

   /home

Can any one help me how can i pass one extra parameter from login page to home page. If i make session before login then it redirect directly to home page . So there is any way to pass project name from login page to home page.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your extra parameter just like the username and password from the form and setup an [AuthenticationDetailsSource](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationDetailsSource.html) in your authentication processing filter (in your HTTP security config; Java/XML whatever it may be) and get the required details from request added to your [Authentication](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) object (as details; declared in `AbstractAuthenticationToken`). Below is a hint on how you can register your `AuthenticationDetailsSource` to the filter.

```
AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter#setAuthenticationDetailsSource(
        AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest, ?> authenticationDetailsSource)
```

The authentication processing filter (I'll assume you're using the default [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html) for form login) will do the rest by calling `setDetails(request, authRequest)` inside `Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException`. I'll suggest you to go through the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter to find out how can you extract the exact details you wish to (through `request.getParameter("param_name")` at the end).

Once you set your parameter in the authentication object, you can use an [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) to access it inside your app (now you can use session too).